# Placing an option value into a table

Tags: php

came across a problem for my coursework when trying to place selected items from my database into a table, here is my code:

```
        echo '<br>';
        $describeQuery='Select Distinct current_location From Current_Location';
        $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery);
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';

        echo "<table border='1', width='15%'><tr><th>Locations</th></tr>";"
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<tr><td>" "<option value=\"Location1\">" . $row['current_location'] . </option>" "</td></tr>";                
        }

        echo "</table>";
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? The error mentions that I have no ',' or ';' tags, therefore it never ends, however I cannot find this error through messing with the program a bit.

Sorry for any formatting issues, still adjusting to the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `double-quotes`  at the end of the 6th line and then you should modify the `while` loop's echo like this:

```
echo '<br>';
$describeQuery='Select Distinct current_location From Current_Location';
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';

echo "<table border='1', width='15%'><tr><th>Locations</th></tr>";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      echo "<tr><td><option value='Location1'>" . $row['current_location'] . "</option></td></tr>";                
    }   
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @Charliejb Cool. Don't forget to tick my answer as answer and up-vote it. Cheers.